Is a series of constant term $1-r$ Abel summable to 1?
Let $0\le r < 1$. For a given $r,$ clearly,
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-r)
$$
diverges since $1-r>0$ is constant. On the other hand, letting $A(r) = \sum (1-r)r^i$. I thought
$$
\lim_{r\to 1} A(r) = \lim_{r\to 1} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-r)r^i= \lim_{r\to 1} (1-r)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} r^i = \lim_{r\to 1} (1-r) \frac{1}{1-r} = 1.
$$
Therefore, I think $\sum (1-r)$ is an Abel-summable divergent series. Am I wrong?

As I understand, $r$ is a constant here. So you can't multiply by $r^i$ and take $r\to 1$. You need to multiply by $x^i$ and take $x\to 1^-$. It's an easy computation, you will see that the limit is not finite.

For the  Abel sum of a series $\sum a_n$, computed as $\lim_{r \to 1}\sum a_n r^n$, we cannot have $a_n$ depending on $r$.

I see. It makes sense now. Thanks.

The sum of constant terms can always be reduced to the sum of ones by linearity:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-r)=(1-r)\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1
$$
The sum of constant terms is not Abel summable:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac1{1-z}
$$
which diverges when $z\to 1^-$. A related way to sum the divergent series, you need to perform an asymptotic expansion in $N=\frac1{\ln z}$ (morally the cutoff index):
$$
\frac1{1-e^{1/N}}=-N+\frac12+o(1)
$$
The idea is the the constant term is the value attributed to the divergent series. In Abel summation, the constant is leading order, so this is a generalization. You can therefore sum the series to:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1=\frac12
$$
This agrees with other methods like zeta regularization since $\zeta(0)=-\frac12$. There is no signe discrepancy with the sign since:
$$
\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}
$$
Formally:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty1=-\frac12
$$
so adding the $n=0$ term gives the previous result. Thanks to user76284 for pointing out the mistake.
Hope this helps.

There's a small error here: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 = -\frac{1}{2}$ (the precise indices matter for a divergent series).

@user76284 thanks for pointing it out! Corrected accordingly

Also, shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{1-\exp(1/N)} = -N + \frac{1}{2} + o(1)$?

Argh forgot that. Should be ok now
